# prevent kitchen aspirator exhale from other condominium kitchens

Tags: kitchens, oven, smell

first of all sorry my bad english.
I live in a condominium in a rented house and the owner installed very cheap appliances in the kitchen. 
The condominium has the kitchen aspirator pipe for the exhaust in common with my neighbours. Now when the neighbous cook i het from the aspirator the smell of what they're cooking and that very unconfortable. Is there any electric option to close the aspirator pipe and open it when i turn my aspirator on?

Comment: There is a common main duct pipe, but presumably you have your own fan, motor and duct leading to the common duct, right? The only thing I can think of is for you to turn on your exhaust fan anytime another user has theirs running,

Comment: Yeah but thats frustrating, im was looking for some kind of valve maybe electric that open when i turn on my fan...thanks anyway

Comment: Our range hood has a light flapper (check) valve which prevents backflow. This is designed to prevent cold, dense outside air from passing down the roof duct into the house. When we turn on the vent fan it lifts the flapper. When we turn it off I can hear the flapper click shut. In your case a valve like this would prevent backflow from other units.